# Is there a way to wait for node-fetch reponse in nested iteration of object, before exiting nested for-loop?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, fetch-api

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate of another question, but I honestly don't know where to turn. I've been banging my head agaist a wall for a week now and cannot wrap my head around how to make this work as I expect. I've tried two different approaches, one with Object.keys().forEach async/await/fetch and now the current approach. Both of them basically do the same thing and fail in the same manner. I'm completely new to this and are probably in way over my head, but then again I feel I'm so close to a working solution, that there probably is a simple change to solve the problem I'm having. (I did make it work by wrapping the for in a function and calling it from another function which had the "writeToFile"-function delayed by a timer.)

What I expect:

I read a json-file and put that into the object kartlag, where I read the value wmsurl from kartlag and the value legendeurl from underlag. I log every action to errors.log and actions.log, just so I can keep track of what's happening. I expect the nested for-loop to finish and the results of those requests to get back, before the "writeToFile(kartlag)"-function is triggered.

What I get: writeToFile(kartlag) is triggered before the results of my fetches cone back, so those keys in kartlag that should've been deleted(because they are not working as expected) are still present in my output.

What I think is happening, is that the for-loop is happy as long as the requests are fired off, all though I'm not happy until the result comes back.

Is there an easy fix for this issue, or will I have to chose a completely different approach here?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));

let kartlag = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('kartlag.json')); 
let action;
let files = ['actions.log', 'errors.log', 'kartlag2.json']

for (const bup of files) {
if (fs.existsSync(bup)) {
  fs.unlink(bup, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // if no error, file has been deleted successfully
  action = bup + ' deleted!';
  writeToLog(action);
});
}
}

    for (var key in kartlag) {
        if (kartlag[key].underlag) {
            for (var ul in kartlag[key].underlag) {
                if (kartlag[key].underlag[ul].legendeurl) {
                    sjekkUnderlag(key, ul);
                } else {
                    console.log('Mangler lengendeurl');
                }
            } 
        } else {
            console.log('Har ikke underlag');
        }
        if (kartlag[key].wmsurl) {
            sjekkHovedlag(key);
        }
    }


writeToFile(kartlag);

function sjekkHovedlag (key) {
      fetch(kartlag[key].wmsurl)
      .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
              action = kartlag[key].wmsurl + ' hovedlag testet OK ' + key;
              writeToLog(action);
          } else {
            action = kartlag[key].wmsurl + ' ikke 200: ' +  key;
            writeErrors(action);
            delete kartlag[key];
          }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        writeErrors(err);
        delete kartlag[key];
      });
}

function sjekkUnderlag (key, ul) {
     fetch(kartlag[key].underlag[ul].legendeurl)
    .then((response) => {
        let cont = response.headers.get('content-type')
        if (response.status === 200 && cont === 'image/png') {
          action = kartlag[key].underlag[ul].legendeurl + ' underlag testet OK ' + key + ' ' + ul ;
          writeToLog(action);
        } else {
          action = kartlag[key].underlag[ul].legendeurl + ' ikke 200 eller returnerer ikke bilde kartlag: ' +  kartlag[key].id + ' underlag: ' + kartlag[key].underlag[ul].id;
          writeErrors(action);
          delete kartlag[key].underlag[ul];    
        }  
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        writeErrors(err);
        delete kartlag[key].underlag[ul]
    });
}

function writeToFile (kartlag) {
  fs.writeFileSync('kartlag2.json', JSON.stringify(kartlag, null, 2));
}

function writeToLog (action) {
  fs.appendFileSync('actions.log', action + '\n');
}

function writeErrors (action) {
  fs.appendFileSync('errors.log', action + '\n');
}
```

Comment: If I understand well, "sjekkUnderlag" and "sjekkHovedlag" must completes before next iteration and it doesn't ?

Comment: Yes, the should complete fully, as in recieve the responses from the fetching calls, before writeToFile is executed.

What I'm trying to achieve is to check all these URLs, if they give the correct response and remove them from the JSON if they are not functioning properly. I'm feeding this JSON into some other pipeline further down the road, that does not have the proper error handling, so I'm trying to scrub funky URLs from this list.